# How to get complete address from latitude and longitude?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I want to get following values from Latitude and Longitude in android

1. Street Address
2. City / State
3. Zip
4. Complete Address

How to achieve this?

Comment: You need to use Google's Reverse API for same

Comment: i have one doubt, its completely free for unlimited use or pricing ?

Answer (score 592, accepted):

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5

String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL
```

For more info of available details, Look at [Android-Location-Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html)

Comment: address you have provided is complete address or street address?

Comment: address is a street address, also look at addresses list I think it contains all detail which you need..

Comment: Postal code (ZIP code for United States), if available, is:
final String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();

Comment: `getAddressLine()` is not reliable for getting city/country as address lines can vary depending on level of geocoding detail.  Use `getLocality()` and `getCountryName()` instead.

Comment: addresses.get(0).getPostalCode() is still returning NULL, any other way to get it..or is it something it's working only for some specific region only !!!

Comment: @Shubh - If address line is not present then it returns **NULL**. Same as applicable for City name and Country name. If data is not available then it returns **NULL**. Test it with known latitude, longitude.

Comment: Thanks...is there any other way to get it?

Comment: @Shubh - Try this url - `"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latitude + ","+ longitude + "&sensor=true"`. It will return Json response.

Comment: it's same..response result not have any attribute to read zip_code.

Comment: thanks for correct answer but if try catch block not added, it will gives IOException error.

Comment: Accidentally voted this answer down, now it's locked unless the answer is edited. Sorry bro!

Comment: Geocoder lookup can take lots of time. It's much better to call it an a separate thread. As in [Google Doc example](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html)

Comment: You don't need to specify `Locale.getDefault()`, `new Geocoder(this)` will use the default locale automatically.

Comment: @user370305 this is asking api key to access that url.

Comment: Is there a way to get just the street number?

Answer (score 71):

Try this My friend

```
 private String getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) {
            String strAdd = "";
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
                if (addresses != null) {
                    Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                    StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

                    for (int i = 0; i <= returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    }
                    strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                    Log.w("My Current loction address", strReturnedAddress.toString());
                } else {
                    Log.w("My Current loction address", "No Address returned!");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.w("My Current loction address", "Canont get Address!");
            }
            return strAdd;
        }
```

Comment: Nice Anwer.Thank you.

Comment: In the for-loop use i <= returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex() as the index might be 0

Comment: it gives  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Answer (score 30):

**City** & **Country** are not Always getting in  address Line 1 & Line 2...

Example is [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html)

So,

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());

List<Address> addresses  = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, 1);
String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
String zip = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
```

Answer (score 11):

If you use Kotlin language, I create this method to get the address location directly

```
private fun getAddress(latLng: LatLng): String {
    val geocoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault())
    val addresses: List<Address>?
    val address: Address?
    var addressText = ""

    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1)

    if (addresses.isNotEmpty()) {
        address = addresses[0]
        addressText = address.getAddressLine(0)
    } else{
        addressText = "its not appear"
    }
    return addressText
}
```

But this method just return the String value when you call this method

If you want to get all address you just use this method/function

```
fun getAddress(latLng: LatLng){
    val geocoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault())
    val addresses: List<Address>?
    val address: Address?
    var fulladdress = ""
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1)

    if (addresses.isNotEmpty()) {
        address = addresses[0]
        fulladdress = address.getAddressLine(0) // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex
        var city = address.getLocality();
        var state = address.getAdminArea();
        var country = address.getCountryName();
        var postalCode = address.getPostalCode();
        var knownName = address.getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL
    } else{
        fulladdress = "Location not found"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**In onCreate()..**

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 0, this);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

    if (location == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS signal not found",
                3000).show();
    }
    if (location != null) {
        Log.e("location", "location--" + location);
        Log.e("latitude at beginning",
                "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" + location.getLatitude());
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
```

**Write the code in onLocationChanged()**

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    Log.e("latitude", "latitude--" + latitude);

    try {
        Log.e("latitude", "inside latitude--" + latitude);
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); 
            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
            String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); 

            locationTxt.setText(address + " " + city + " " + country);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for the term Geocoding.

The short story is you need to do:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```

To do more you should read up on the Geocoder [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html).

Comment: but you need to check your country supports the geocoding.   http://elocation.oracle.com/geocoder/gcdemo.jsp

Answer (score 6):

```
  public static String getAddressFromLatLng(Context context, LatLng latLng) {
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
        return addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just Use this method and pass your lat, long.

```
public static void getAddress(Context context, double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE{
    //Set Address
    try {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
            String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL
            Log.d(TAG, "getAddress:  address" + address);
            Log.d(TAG, "getAddress:  city" + city);
            Log.d(TAG, "getAddress:  state" + state);
            Log.d(TAG, "getAddress:  postalCode" + postalCode);
            Log.d(TAG, "getAddress:  knownName" + knownName);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Its very easy to get complete address from the Latitude and Longitude using Geocoder class. Following the code sample. Hope this helps!

```
 if (l != null) {
        val lat = l.latitude
        val lon = l.longitude

        val geocoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault())
        val addresses: List<Address>

        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1) 

        val address = addresses[0].getAddressLine(0)
        val address2 = addresses[0].getAddressLine(1)
        val city = addresses[0].locality
        val state = addresses[0].adminArea
        val country = addresses[0].countryName
        val postalCode = addresses[0].postalCode
        val knownName = addresses[0].featureName

        val message =
                "Emergency situation. Call for help. My location is: " + address + "." + "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + lat + "," + lon

    }
```

You can use only the address value as it gives you all the complete address. If you want individual components, you can use others as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use this it work for me :D

Retrieve json data of the latitude and longitude.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIzaSyAr29XeWWAeWZcrOgjjfs3iSnqkWtAz4No&latlng=2.1812,102.4266&sensor=true

Change latitude , longitude with your own place.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=<\API_KEY_HERE>&latlng="latitude","longitude"&sensor=true

You can change the <\API_KEY_HERE> with your own key.

Need to enable api service in google console for new api key.

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 3):

**Using geocoder you can get something like this!**

[image]

```
           try {
                Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocation(origin.latitude, origin.longitude, 1);
                address.setText("Loading...");
                if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                    String locality = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                    String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                    String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                    String sub_admin = addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
                    String city = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
                    String pincode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                    String locality_city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    String sub_localoty = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
                    if (locality != null && country != null) {
                        address.setText(locality + ", " + (sub_localoty != null ? sub_localoty + ", " : "")  + (locality_city != null ? locality_city + ", " : "" ) + (city != null ? city + ", " : "")  + (sub_admin != null ? sub_admin + ", " : "") + (state != null ? state + ", " : "") + country + ", " + (pincode != null ? pincode : ""));
                    } else {
                        address.setText("Location could not be fetched...");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                address.setText("Location could not be fetched...");
                e.printStackTrace(); // getFromLocation() may sometimes fail
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer in kotlin format

```
private fun getAddressInfo(latitude:Double, longitude:Double){
    val geocoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault())
    val addresses: List<Address> = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1)

    val address: String = addresses[0].getAddressLine(0)
    val city: String = addresses[0].locality
    val state: String = addresses[0].adminArea
    val country: String = addresses[0].countryName
    val postalCode: String = addresses[0].postalCode
    val knownName: String = addresses[0].featureName
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  Geocoder geocoder =new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
 // Get the current location from the input parameter list
  Location loc = params[0];
 // Create a list to contain the result address
  List<Address> addresses = null;
  try {
     addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
             loc.getLongitude(), 10);
 } catch (IOException e1) {
           Log.e("LocationSampleActivity","IO Exception in getFromLocation()");
      e1.printStackTrace();

 } catch (IllegalArgumentException e2) {
 // Error message to post in the log
 String errorString = "Illegal arguments " +
         Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()) +
         " , " +
         Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()) +
         " passed to address service";
 Log.e("LocationSampleActivity", errorString);
 e2.printStackTrace();

 }
 Address address=null;
 String zip=null;
 String city=null;
 String state=null;
 StringBuffer st=new StringBuffer();
 // If the reverse geocode returned an address
 if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
 String       add=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)+","
  +addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea()+","
  +addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
  city=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
  state=addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
     // Get the first address
  for(int i=0 ;i<addresses.size();i++){
  address = addresses.get(i);
   if(address.getPostalCode()!=null){
zip=address.getPostalCode();
break;
     }

      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use the following code to get the address.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;

public class GPSService extends Service implements LocationListener {

// saving the context for later use
private final Context mContext;

// if GPS is enabled
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
// if Network is enabled
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
// if Location co-ordinates are available using GPS or Network
public boolean isLocationAvailable = false;

// Location and co-ordinates coordinates
Location mLocation;
double mLatitude;
double mLongitude;

// Minimum time fluctuation for next update (in milliseconds)
private static final long TIME = 30000;
// Minimum distance fluctuation for next update (in meters)
private static final long DISTANCE = 20;

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager mLocationManager;

public GPSService(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

}

/**
 * Returs the Location
 * 
 * @return Location or null if no location is found
 */
public Location getLocation() {
    try {

        // Getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // If GPS enabled, get latitude/longitude using GPS Services
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, TIME, DISTANCE, this);
            if (mLocationManager != null) {
                mLocation = mLocationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (mLocation != null) {
                    mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
                    mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                    isLocationAvailable = true; // setting a flag that
                                                // location is available
                    return mLocation;
                }
            }
        }

        // If we are reaching this part, it means GPS was not able to fetch
        // any location
        // Getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, TIME, DISTANCE, this);
            if (mLocationManager != null) {
                mLocation = mLocationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (mLocation != null) {
                    mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
                    mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                    isLocationAvailable = true; // setting a flag that
                                                // location is available
                    return mLocation;
                }
            }
        }
        // If reaching here means, we were not able to get location neither
        // from GPS not Network,
        if (!isGPSEnabled) {
            // so asking user to open GPS
            askUserToOpenGPS();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // if reaching here means, location was not available, so setting the
    // flag as false
    isLocationAvailable = false;
    return null;
}

/**
 * Gives you complete address of the location
 * 
 * @return complete address in String
 */
public String getLocationAddress() {

    if (isLocationAvailable) {

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
        // Get the current location from the input parameter list
        // Create a list to contain the result address
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            /*
             * Return 1 address.
             */
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mLatitude, mLongitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return ("IO Exception trying to get address:" + e1);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e2) {
            // Error message to post in the log
            String errorString = "Illegal arguments "
                    + Double.toString(mLatitude) + " , "
                    + Double.toString(mLongitude)
                    + " passed to address service";
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return errorString;
        }
        // If the reverse geocode returned an address
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            // Get the first address
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            /*
             * Format the first line of address (if available), city, and
             * country name.
             */
            String addressText = String.format(
                    "%s, %s, %s",
                    // If there's a street address, add it
                    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address
                            .getAddressLine(0) : "",
                    // Locality is usually a city
                    address.getLocality(),
                    // The country of the address
                    address.getCountryName());
            // Return the text
            return addressText;
        } else {
            return "No address found by the service: Note to the developers, If no address is found by google itself, there is nothing you can do about it.";
        }
    } else {
        return "Location Not available";
    }

}



/**
 * get latitude
 * 
 * @return latitude in double
 */
public double getLatitude() {
    if (mLocation != null) {
        mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
    }
    return mLatitude;
}

/**
 * get longitude
 * 
 * @return longitude in double
 */
public double getLongitude() {
    if (mLocation != null) {
        mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
    }
    return mLongitude;
}

/**
 * close GPS to save battery
 */
public void closeGPS() {
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(GPSService.this);
    }
}

/**
 * show settings to open GPS
 */
public void askUserToOpenGPS() {
    AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    mAlertDialog.setTitle("Location not available, Open GPS?")
    .setMessage("Activate GPS to use use location services?")
    .setPositiveButton("Open Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).show();
}

/** 
 * Updating the location when location changes
 */
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create class

```
public class GeoLocation {

private Context mContext;

private String mLatitude;
private String mLongtitude;
private String mStreet;
private String mHouseNumber;
private String mPostalCode;
private String mCity;

private Location mMarkerLocation;

public GeoLocation (Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

public String getStreet () {
    return mStreet;
}

public String getHouseNumber () {
    return mHouseNumber;
}

public String getPostalCode () {
    return mPostalCode;
}

public String getCity () {
    return mCity;
}

public String getLatitude () {
    return mLatitude;
}

public String getLongtitude () {
    return mLongtitude;
}

// Lookup address via reverse geolocation
// Call this one
public void lookUpAddress (Location markerLocation) {
    mMarkerLocation = markerLocation;
    if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
        (new GetAddressTask(mContext)).execute();
    }
}

public class GetAddressTask extends AsyncTask<android.location.Location, Void, String> {

    public GetAddressTask (Context context) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground (android.location.Location... params) {
        Geocoder geocoder =
                new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
        android.location.Location location = params[0];

        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            if (mMarkerLocation != null) {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(mMarkerLocation.getLatitude(),
                        mMarkerLocation.getLongitude(), 1);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e("ComplaintLocation",
                    "IO Exception in getFromLocation()", exception);

            return ("IO Exception trying to get address");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {
            String errorString = "Illegal arguments " +
                    Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + " , " +
                    Double.toString(location.getLongitude()) + " passed to address service";
            Log.e("LocationSampleActivity", errorString, exception);

            return errorString;
        }

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);

            if (address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0) {
                return String.format(
                        "%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s",
                        address.getLatitude(), // 0
                        address.getLongitude(), // 1
                        address.getThoroughfare(), // 2
                        address.getSubThoroughfare(), //3
                        address.getPostalCode(), // 4
                        address.getLocality()); // 5
            } else {
                return String.format(
                        "%s/%s/%s/%s",
                        address.getLatitude(), // 0
                        address.getLongitude(), // 1
                        address.getPostalCode(), // 2
                        address.getLocality()); // 3
            }
        } else return "No address found";
    }

    // Format address string after lookup
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (String address) {

        String[] addressFields = TextUtils.split(address, "/");
        Log.d("ADDRESS ARRAY", Arrays.toString(addressFields));

        // Workaround: doInBackground can only return Strings instead of, for example, an
        // Address instance or a String[] directly. To be able to use TextUtils.isEmpty()
        // on fields returned by this method, set each String that currently reads "null" to
        // a null reference
        for (int fieldcnt = 0; fieldcnt < addressFields.length; ++fieldcnt) {
            if (addressFields[fieldcnt].equals("null"))
                addressFields[fieldcnt] = null;
        }

        switch (addressFields.length) {
            case 4:
                mStreet = null;
                mHouseNumber = null;
                mLatitude = addressFields[0];
                mLongtitude = addressFields[1];
                mPostalCode = addressFields[2];
                mCity = addressFields[3];
                break;
            case 6:
                mLatitude = addressFields[0];
                mLongtitude = addressFields[1];
                mStreet = addressFields[2];
                mHouseNumber = addressFields[3];
                mPostalCode = addressFields[4];
                mCity = addressFields[5];
                break;
            default:
                mLatitude = null;
                mLongtitude = null;
                mStreet = null;
                mHouseNumber = null;
                mPostalCode = null;
                mCity = null;
                break;
        }

        Log.d("GeoLocation Street", mStreet);
        Log.d("GeoLocation No.", mHouseNumber);
        Log.d("GeoLocation Postalcode", mPostalCode);
        Log.d("GeoLocation Locality", mCity);
        Log.d("GeoLocation Lat/Lng", "[" + mLatitude + ", " + mLongtitude + 
    "]");
    }
 }
   }
```

You then instantiate it using

```
GeoLocation geoLocation = new GeoLocation(getActivity()); // or (this) if 
called from an activity and not from a fragment
mGeoLocation.lookUpAddress(LOCATION_FROM_MAP);
```

Answer (score 2):

1 - You create variables for LocationManager and LocationListener in onCreate method.

2 - Check if there is a permission so execute the location updates and get lastKnownLocation from locationManager else you ask for permission

3 - Create onRequestPermissionResult in main class and check if there is a permission then execute the location updates

4 - Create separated method which includes Geocoder variable and create a list to put the coordinates from your location,
so to be safe you check if the List is exist and if each info we want in that list is exist, then you use (getThoroughfare  ==> for Street Address), (getLocality ==> for City / State), (getPostalCode ==> for Zip), (getAdminArea ==> for Complete Address)

5 - Finally you call that method after checking the permission with (lastKnownLocation parameter ==> to show address when the App runs) and in onLocationChanged with (location parameter ==> to show address when location changes)

Code part:

```
LocationManager locationManager;

LocationListener locationListener;

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager  = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            updateLocation(location);

        }
        @Override public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

        Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        updateLocation(lastKnownLocation);

    }else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
    }
}


public void updateLocation ( Location location){


    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),1);

        String address = "Could not find location :(";

        if (listAddresses != null && listAddresses.size() > 0) {

            if (listAddresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() != null) {

                address = listAddresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() + " ";
            }

            if (listAddresses.get(0).getLocality() != null) {

                address += listAddresses.get(0).getLocality() + " ";
            }

            if (listAddresses.get(0).getPostalCode() != null) {

                address += listAddresses.get(0).getPostalCode() + " ";
            }

            if (listAddresses.get(0).getAdminArea() != null) {

                address += listAddresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            }
        }

        Log.i("Address",address);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that no-one has yet provided the solution suggested by Google Docs (https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address#java). The correct solution should use an IntentService to make the network call for reverse geocoding.

An intent service is used rather than an AsyncTask as it is not tied to any specific activity. ie. it has its own lifecycle. The IntentService will stop itself when the Geocoding is finished.

```
public class GeocodingService extends IntentService {

    public GeocodingService() {
        super("GeocodingService");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null) {
            return;
        }

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        String errorMessage = "";
        BCCDatabase BCCDatabase = skicompanion.skicompanion.storage.BCCDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        // Get the location passed to this service through an extra.
        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(
                "location");
        long trackID = intent.getLongExtra("trackID", -1);

        List<Address> addresses = null;
        String addressString = "";

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    location.getLatitude(),
                    location.getLongitude(),
                    1);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            // Catch network or other I/O problems.
            errorMessage = "service not available";
            Log.d(Constants.SkiCompanionDebug, errorMessage, ioException);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
            // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
            errorMessage = "invalid lat long used";
            Log.d(Constants.SkiCompanionDebug, errorMessage + ". " +
                    "Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() +
                    ", Longitude = " +
                    location.getLongitude(), illegalArgumentException);
        }

        // Handle case where no address was found.
        if (addresses == null || addresses.size()  == 0) {
            if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
                errorMessage = "no address found";
                Log.d(Constants.SkiCompanionDebug, errorMessage);
            }
        } else {
            if(addresses.get(0).getLocality() != null){
                addressString += addresses.get(0).getLocality() + ", ";
            }
            if(addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() != null){
                addressString += addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + ", ";
            }
            if(addresses.get(0).getCountryName() != null){
                addressString += addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            }
            //updating DB
            BCCDatabase.setTrackLocation(trackID, addressString);

            Log.d(Constants.SkiCompanionDebug, "address found: "+ addressString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, you should use the IntentService for reverse geocoding.

Answer (score 2):

For Android Tiramasu and above (API 33), they added a listener which makes it quite easier. I would also suggest to use admin and subAdmin for state and city as locality returns null for lot of countries like UK.

```
private fun getAddressFromCoordinates(lat: Double, lng: Double) {
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                val addressForAPI33AndAbove =
                    geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1,
                        object : GeocodeListener {
                            override fun onGeocode(p0: MutableList<Address>) {
                                val address = p0[0]
                                val userAddress = loadUserAddress(address, lat, lng)
                                //use userAddress :)
                            }
                        })
            } else {

                val address = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1)?.get(0)
                if (address != null) {
                    val userAddress = loadUserAddress(address, lat, lng)
                    //use userAddress :)
                } else {
                    //todo: Snackbar error msg
        }
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Utils.log("Check internet: ${e.message}")
        }
}

private fun loadUserAddress(address: Address, lat: Double, lng: Double): UserAddress {
        return UserAddress(
            postcode = address.postalCode,
            fullAddressLine = address.getAddressLine(0),
            latitude = lat,
            longitude = lng,
            adminArea = address.adminArea,
            subAdminArea = address.subAdminArea,
            country = address.countryName
        )
}
```

Let me know if I made any mistakes. Happy to edit the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code using geocoder:

```
  Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
  List<Address> geoAddresses = geoAddresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
  if (geoAddresses.size() > 0) {
      String mUserLocation = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { //Since it return only four value we declare this as static.
           mUserLocation = mUserLocation + geoAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i).replace(",", "") + ", ";
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getAddress(LatLng latLng) {
    String cAddress = "";
    if (latLng == null) {
        errorMessage = "no_location_data_provided";
        Log.wtf(TAG, errorMessage);
        return "";
    }
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    // Address found using the Geocoder.
    List<Address> addresses = null;

    try {
        // Using getFromLocation() returns an array of Addresses for the area immediately
        // surrounding the given latitude and longitude. The results are a best guess and are
        // not guaranteed to be accurate.
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                latLng.latitude,
                latLng.longitude,
                // In this sample, we get just a single address.
                1);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        // Catch network or other I/O problems.
        errorMessage = "service_not_available";
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, ioException);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
        // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
        errorMessage = "invalid_lat_long_used";
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage + ". " +
                "Latitude = " + latLng.latitude +
                ", Longitude = " + latLng.longitude, illegalArgumentException);
    }

    // Handle case where no address was found.
    if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
        if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
            errorMessage = "no_address_found";
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        }
    } else {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        ArrayList<String> addressFragments = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Fetch the address lines using {@code getAddressLine},
        // join them, and send them to the thread. The {@link android.location.address}
        // class provides other options for fetching address details that you may prefer
        // to use. Here are some examples:
        // getLocality() ("Mountain View", for example)
        // getAdminArea() ("CA", for example)
        // getPostalCode() ("94043", for example)
        // getCountryCode() ("US", for example)
        // getCountryName() ("United States", for example)
        String allAddress = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
            addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
            allAddress += address.getAddressLine(i) + " ";
        }
        if (address.getAdminArea() != null) {
            state = address.getAdminArea();
        } else {
            state = "";
        }
        if (address.getLocality() != null) {
            city = address.getLocality();
        } else {
            city = "";
        }
        if (address.getPostalCode() != null) {
            postalCode = address.getPostalCode();
        } else {
            postalCode = "";
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "address_found");
        //driverAddress = TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"), addressFragments);
        cAddress = allAddress;
        Log.e("result", cAddress.toString());
    }
    return cAddress;
}
```

### You Can use this method for geocoding proper complete Address

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this to get complete address from latitude and longitude :

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

         ...

  private Geocoder geocoder;
  private TextView mAddressTxtVu;

         ...


  // I assume that you got latitude and longitude correctly 

  mLatitude  =  20.23232
  mLongitude =  32.999

  String errorMessage = "";

  geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());

  List<Address> addresses = null;

  try {
              addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                       mlattitude,
                       mlongitude,
                       1);
      } catch (IOException e) {
              errorMessage = getString(R.string.service_not_available);
              Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, e);
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
                        // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
              errorMessage = getString(R.string.invalid_lat_long_used);
              Log.e(TAG, errorMessage + ". " + "Latitude = " + mlattitude +", Longitude = " + mlongitude, illegalArgumentException);
      }

      // Handle case where no address was found.
      if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
             if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
                      errorMessage = getString(R.string.no_address_found);
                      Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
             }

      } else {
             Address address = addresses.get(0);
             ArrayList<String> addressFragments = new ArrayList<String>();

             // Fetch the address lines using getAddressLine,
             // join them, and send them to the thread.
             for (int i = 0; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                      addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
             }
             // Log.i(TAG, getString(R.string.address_found));


    mAddressTxtVu.setText(TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"),
                                addressFragments));
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (working)

```
public void GetLocation() throws IOException {

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        }, 200);

        return;
    } else {



        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location.getLongitude() + " , " + location.getLatitude());

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + s);

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        });
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

        if (location == null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "GPS signal not found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (location != null) {
            Log.e("location", "location--" + location);
            Log.e("latitude at beginning",
                    "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" + location.getLatitude());
            // onLocationChanged(location);
        }


        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
        String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();

        Log.d(TAG, "GetLocation: address " + address + " city " + city + " state " + state + " country " + country + " postalCode " + postalCode + " knownName " + knownName);
    }
}
```