# Remove a marker from a GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps

In the new Google Maps API for Android, we can [add a marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#add_a_marker), but there is no way to (easily) remove one.

My solution is to keep the markers in a map and redraw the map when I want to remove a marker, but it is not very efficient.

```java
private final Map<String, MarkerOptions> mMarkers = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, MarkerOptions>();

private void add(String name, LatLng ll) {
  final MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(ll).title(name);
  mMarkers.put(name, marker);

  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      mMap.addMarker(marker);
    }
  });
}

private void remove(String name) {
  mMarkers.remove(name);

  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      mMap.clear();

      for (MarkerOptions item : mMarkers.values()) {
        mMap.addMarker(item);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Why do you use a Runnable() to add the markers?

Comment: To do it on the UI thread

Comment: use mMap.clear() to clear all markers

Answer (score 281, accepted):

The method signature for [`addMarker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#addMarker%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions%29) is:

```
public final Marker addMarker (MarkerOptions options)
```

So when you add a marker to a `GoogleMap` by specifying the options for the marker, you should save the [`Marker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html) object that is returned (instead of the `MarkerOptions` object that you used to create it).  This object allows you to change the marker state later on.  When you are finished with the marker, you can call [`Marker.remove()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#remove%28%29) to remove it from the map.

As an aside, if you only want to hide it temporarily, you can toggle the visibility of the marker by calling [`Marker.setVisible(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#setVisible%28boolean%29).

Comment: This is not working for me. marker.setVisible(false), marker.remove(), even markerManager.remove(marker) is not affecting the map. Markers still remains. any hints?

Comment: See my comment below about holding onto a marker, while it holds little use after it has been removed from the map, if you should decide to examine its values.. the Remove method sets the tag value to null...

Answer (score 42):

Add the marker to the map like this

```
Marker markerName = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Title"));
```

Then you'll be able to use the remove method, it will remove only that marker

```
markerName.remove();
```

Answer (score 36):

to clear all scribbles in the map use

```
map.clear()
```

Comment: This clears all overlays on the map, not just a marker as the question suggests.

Answer (score 8):

If you use Kotlin language you just add this code:

Create global variables of `GoogleMap` and `Marker` types.

I use variable marker to make variable marker value can change directly

```
private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
private lateinit var marker: Marker
```

And I use this function/method to add the marker on my map:

```
private fun placeMarkerOnMap(location: LatLng) {
    val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(location)
    val titleStr = getAddress(location)
    markerOptions.title(titleStr)
    marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions)
}
```

After I create the function I place this code on the `onMapReady()` to remove the marker and create a new one:

```
map.setOnMapClickListener { location ->
        map.clear()
        marker.remove()
        placeMarkerOnMap(location)
    }
```

It's bonus if you want to display the address location when you click the marker add this code to hide and show the marker address but you need a method to get the address location. I got the code from this post: [How to get complete address from latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409195/how-to-get-complete-address-from-latitude-and-longitude)

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener {marker ->
        if (marker.isInfoWindowShown){
            marker.hideInfoWindow()
        }else{
            marker.showInfoWindow()
        }
        true
    }
```

Comment: The marker.remove() or google.clear() removes all the marker which are not being updated it only shows the updated marker after clearing the map or removing the marker

Answer (score 6):

if marker exist remove last marker. if marker  does not exist create current marker

```
Marker currentMarker = null;
if (currentMarker!=null) {
    currentMarker.remove();
    currentMarker=null;
}

if (currentMarker==null) {
    currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(arg0).
    icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a NOTE, something that I wasted hours tracking down tonight...

If you decide to hold onto a marker for some reason, after you have REMOVED it from a map...  getTag will return NULL, even though the remaining get values will return with the values you set them to when the marker was created...

TAG value is set to NULL if you ever remove a marker, and then attempt to reference it.

Seems like a bug to me...

Comment: Not sure it's related, but I have my markers in a hashmap and if I call `marker.remove()` and then `markers.clear()`, the hashmap gets cleared, but the markers stay on the map. The code works if I remove `markers.clear()`

Answer (score 2):

Make a global variable to keep track of marker

```
private Marker currentLocationMarker;
```

//Remove old marker

```
            if (null != currentLocationMarker) {
                currentLocationMarker.remove();
            }
```

// Add updated marker in and move the camera

```
            currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(getLatitude(), getLongitude()))
                    .title("You are now Here").visible(true)
                    .icon(Utils.getMarkerBitmapFromView(getActivity(), R.drawable.auto_front))
                    .snippet("Updated Location"));

            currentLocationMarker.showInfoWindow();
```

Answer (score 2):

use the following code:

```
 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

           marker.remove();
           return true;
       }
   });
```

once you click on **"a marker"**, you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Create array with all markers on add in map.

Later, use:

```
Marker temp = markers.get(markers.size() - 1);
temp.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** If you want to remove a marker you can do it as `marker.remove();`
    alternatively you can also hide the marker instead of removing it as

```
 marker.setVisible(false);
```

and make it visible later whenever needed.
 **2.** However if you want to remove all markers from the map **Use** `map.clear();`
**Note:** `map.clear();` will also remove `Polylines, Circles` etc.
**3.** If you not want to remove `Polylines, Circles` etc. than use a loop to the length of marker (if you have multiple markers) to remove those [Check out the Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218041/removing-markers-in-android/34222153#34222153) **OR** set them Visible false And do not use  `map.clear();` in such case.

Answer (score 1):

For those that are following the example on this [GoogleMaps - MapWithMarker](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/tutorials/kotlin/MapWithMarker) project, you may remove the marker by doing so

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
    googleMap?.apply {

        // Remove marker
        clear()

        val sydney = LatLng(-33.852, 151.211)
        addMarker(
            MarkerOptions()
                .position(sydney)
                .title("Marker in Sydney")
        )
        moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it is updating the current location, and it works fine.

```java
        public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {               
        //here we update the location on the map
        
        LatLng myActualLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        
        if (markerName!=null){  // marker name is declared as a gloval variable.
            markerName.remove();
        }
        
        markerName = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myActualLocation).title("Marker Miami").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
        
        // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myActualLocation).title("Marker Miami").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myActualLocation,18));
        
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin

global variable

```
private var marker: Marker? = null
```

in the function

```
private fun placeMarkerOnMap(location: LatLng) {
        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
           .position(location)
           .title("My Location")
        marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
    }
```

when click

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener { location ->
                mMaps.clear()
                marker?.remove()
                placeMarkerOnMap(location)
            }
```