# How to remove the marker in Google map v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

I added the marker on the map using following method and also kept the marker record

```
public static void  showallLocations() 
    {
        ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> listshow=latLngStoragepreference.getLatlng();
        markerlist=new ArrayList<Marker>();// to keep the marker record so that later we can delete
        if(listshow.size()>0)
        {
        for(int i=0;i<listshow.size();i++)
        {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> Linkedhashmap=listshow.get(i);

        Set mapSet = (Set) Linkedhashmap.entrySet();
        //Create iterator on Set 
        Iterator mapIterator = mapSet.iterator();

        Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) mapIterator.next();
        // getKey Method of HashMap access a key of map
        String keyValue = (String) mapEntry.getKey();
        //getValue method returns corresponding key's value
        String value = (String) mapEntry.getValue();
        String[] parts=value.split("#");
        String Latitude=parts[0];
        String Longitude=parts[1];
        Double Latitudeconverted=Double.parseDouble(Latitude);
        Double Longitudeconverted=Double.parseDouble(Longitude);
        System.out.println(Latitudeconverted+""+Longitudeconverted);
        //show on map
        LatLng latLngs=new LatLng(Latitudeconverted, Longitudeconverted);

        Marker marker=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(
                latLngs)
                .title(keyValue)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_navigate_to)));
        markerlist.add(marker);// keeping the record of marker object

        }
        }


    }
```

in custom baseadapter, I tried to remove the marker but `marker.remove()` is not working

```
holder.btnDeletelocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


        Marker marker=  MainActivity.markerlist.get(position);
        Log.d("MARKERlist before Remove", MainActivity.markerlist.toString());

        Log.d("MARKER Title",marker.getTitle());


        marker.remove();
        marker.setVisible(false);
        Log.d("MARKERlist after Remove", MainActivity.markerlist.toString());



            notifyDataSetChanged();




            }
        });
```

Please help If anybody had gone through the same. Thanks in advance

Comment: See this question,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692398/remove-a-marker-from-a-googlemap

Comment: Does it work if you call `googleMap.clear()` instead of removing single marker?

Comment: @MaciejGórski No it doesn't work it will clear complete map. I got the answer by my own..are you in same issue?

Comment: No. If you have found the solution, post it as an answer and accept, so people looking to help won't read it and people looking for help will learn from you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I Googled lot and found there isn't easy way to remove the marker from map, 
whenever you add the marker to map don't forget to keep its record, like adding it to Map or ArrayList.

```
your_google_map_obj.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()) //this adds Marker on Google Map, you should know it always returns Marker object so that you can use it later especially for removal.
```

so `Marker marker=your_google_map_obj.addMarker(new MarkerOptions())` add this marker object to list or map `markerArraylist.add(marker);` then easily you can extract marker from list by 
`Marker marker=markerArraylist.get(index);` and then call `marker.remove();`

Answer (score 0):

```
Marker currentMarker = null;
if (currentMarker!=null) {
    currentMarker.remove();
    currentMarker=null;
}

if (currentMarker==null) {
    currentMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(arg0).
    icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
}
```

Comment: yes remove my last marker and create current marker

Comment: its work try! i dont undetstand whay -1! its Misleading people!