# How to remove specific marker on Android GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps

**CODE:**

```
private Marker mCurrentMarker;
private ArrayList<Marker> mMarkerArrayList;

@Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        mMarkerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                MarkerOptions marker_onclick = new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude)).title(getString(R.string.now_your_location));
                if (mMarkerArrayList.size() > 0){
                    Marker marker_to_remove = mMarkerArrayList.get(0);
                    marker_to_remove.remove();
                }

                mCurrentMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(marker_onclick);

                mGoogleMap.addMarker(marker_onclick);
                mMarkerArrayList.add(mCurrentMarker);

            }
        });
    }
```

I want that when I click on the map, there will be a marker related in showing clicked location. And marker which has been before being removed. So, there is only one marker related to showing clicked location.

I already know `mGoogleMap.clean();` can clean map, also markers on the map.

But I want to remove specific marker. (Because, On my application, there are many kinds of markers. For example, a home marker is showing where the user's home is, and the bus stop marker is showing where the bus stop is.)

So I made ArrayList and tried to use it.

But it didn't work.

I think when i click on map, `addmarker();` is working well but `.remove();` seems to be not working.

Where is the error?

**How can I remove specific marker only?**

I read: [How to remove the marker in Google map v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185203/how-to-remove-the-marker-in-google-map-v2)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you add a marker on **Map**, you can store it into **HashMap** like this:

```
 HashMap<YourUniqueKey,Marker> hashMapMarker = new HashMap<>();
 Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
 hashMapMarker.put(YourUniqueKey,marker);
```

At the time you want to delete particular marker just get your Maker by **YourUniqueKey** for that marker like this:

```
Marker marker = hashMapMarker.get(YourUniqueKey);
marker.remove();
hashMapMarker.remove(YourUniqueKey);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Manoj Singh Rawal

Comment: YourUniqueKey needs to be a class, according to the compiler.   How do you actually do this?  I am trying to pass a String into it and it will not accept it.

Comment: Nevermind, you have to tell it what type to accept.   So in this case instead of YourUniqueKey you can write <String, Marker>, or <String, String> or whatever data types you want to store here.

Answer (score 2):

use **setOnMarkerClickListener** to do this!

the code is below:

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

        marker.remove();
        return true;
    }
});
```

once you click on a "Marker" you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I went through your code and saw the bug. You are not removing markers from the arrayList.

```
val markerArrayList = ArrayList<Marker>()

    // set map click listener
    googleMap?.setOnMapClickListener {

        if (markerArrayList.size > 0) {
            val markerToRemove = markerArrayList.get(0)

            // remove the maker from list
            markerArrayList.remove(markerToRemove)

            // remove the marker from the map
            markerToRemove.remove()
        }

        // Marker options
        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(it).draggable(true)

        // adds marker to the clicked point
        val currentMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions)

        // Add current marker to array list
        markerArrayList.add(currentMarker)

        // Set default icon
        currentMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))

        // get the location of the clicked point
        val clickedPointLatitude = it.latitude
        mClickedPointLongitude = it.longitude
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is in Kotlin but works and it´s very easy to use.
First create a global arraylist of marks

```
val arrayMarker: MutableList<Marker> = ArrayList()
```

Then, we will populate this array everytime you place a new marker in map this way:

```
val mark1 = mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(latLng))
arrayMarker.add(mark1)
```

Ok, at this point you have the marker in map and the reference saved in array. But now to retrieve this information we will need to create this function to access data.

```
private fun Marker(get: Marker, position: Int): Marker {

    return arrayMarker.get(position)

}
```

Finally, we will retrieve the data from the array and make our code work. In this sample here I've removed all markers like this:

```
val cont=0
    while (cont<arrayMarker.size){
        arrayMarker.get(cont).remove() //or isVisible=false if you just want to hide.
        cont++
    }
```

In case you want to delete a specific just compare the marker you want to remove (it can be done by onMarkClick) and compare with the array:

```
if (clickerMark == arrayMarker.get(position)) { do code here.
```

Hope it helps.