# How remove a single marker by Id?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

this code is remove with click infoWindow

```
// Setting click event handler for InfoWIndow
        googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                // Remove the marker
                marker.remove();
            }
        });
```

but, How remove a single marker by Id without click infoWindow ? i will remove by Button View

Comment: When you are adding markers to the map, then you have to hold those markers instance for this purpose.

Comment: check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692398/remove-a-marker-from-a-googlemap

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add the marker to map don't forget to keep its record, like adding it to Map or ArrayList.

```
your_google_map_obj.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()) //this adds Marker on Google Map, you 
should know it always returns Marker object so that you can use it later especially for 
removal
```

so Marker marker=your_google_map_obj.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()) add this marker object to list or map markerArraylist.add(marker); then easily you can extract marker from list by Marker marker=markerArraylist.get(index); and then call marker.remove();

Other way to do it

After adding the marker it is possible to obtain its reference:

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(..);
```

Marker class has remove method, check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#remove) documentation