# Android after i use map.clear cant add markers

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a method to a add markers to google map v2 and i wish to clear the markers and then add more markers all while in the map. This is how i add the markers which works fine mapLoc being the map itself. Further down the line i then call mapLoc.clear which gets rid of the markers.

I then wish to add more markers to the map but the markers dont appear when i call this method any help?

```
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

           LatLng lg=new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(list.get(i).get(5)), Float.parseFloat(list.get(i).get(6)));

           Marker mark= mapLoc.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lg)
                .title(list.get(i).get(0)).snippet(list.get(i).get(1)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                          .fromResource(R.drawable.mark2)));
        counter++;
        }
```

Comment: Try to save your `Marker` object in the `HashMap`, and then calling `markers.remove()` instead of `map.clear`, finally use your code above to add `additional markers`. For more details, please refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692398/remove-a-marker-from-a-googlemap).

Comment: hrmm seems like a better way of doing it thanks man

Answer (score 2):

As we discuss above:

Try to save your `Marker` object in the `HashMap`, and then calling `markers.remove()` instead of `map.clear`, finally use your code above to add `additional markers`.

For more details, please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692398/remove-a-marker-from-a-googlemap).