# Removing Markers in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a Global array Object like `Marker marker_array[];` and later in Layout click I initialized it as `marker_array = new Marker[8];`. I want to add markers to map on that layout and remove on 2nd click so I created `clickcount` Global variable with zero value.

My proper code is here

```
final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.track_div);

        layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                clickcount++;

                 point_new = new LatLng[8];
                point_new[0] = new LatLng(31.5301843, 74.3207487);
                point_new[1] = new LatLng(31.5214693,74.3236027);
                point_new[2] = new LatLng(31.5194393, 74.3257327);
                point_new[3] = new LatLng(31.4942166, 74.3004533);
                point_new[4] = new LatLng(31.4864646, 74.2911203);
                point_new[5] = new LatLng(31.4803596, 74.2787933);
                point_new[6] = new LatLng(31.4764716, 74.2638203);
                point_new[7] = new LatLng(31.4775236, 74.2628873);

//  initialize marker_array;
                marker_array = new Marker[8];

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "count "+clickcount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
                if (clickcount % 2 == 0) {
                    polyline.setVisible(false);


                    for (int i = 0; i < point_new.length; i++){

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "marker length ="+marker_array.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        marker_array[i].remove();

//                     marker_array.setVisible(false);

                    }
                } else {
                    polyline.setVisible(true);

 for (int i = 0; i < point_new.length; i++) {
                     //   marker_array = new Marker[point_new.length];
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(point_new[i]);

                         marker_array[i] = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                        marker_array[i].setTitle("Points");
                    marker_array[i].setSnippet("Distance = 9.6 km, Time = 20 minute/s");
                    marker_array[i].setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus));


                    }
                }
```

The problem is that it creates all 8 markers But does not remove, Even if in if condition where I'm trying to remove markers `Toast` shows proper length `8`. **Butt** when I remove any of the `marker_array` separately as `marker_array[7]` it removes it.

How can I remove all the markers in **marker_array** without `map.clear();` method because I have some other things like polyline etc that I do not want to remove.

Any effort will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this to add markers

As Global

```
List<Marker> mMarkers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
```

And In your for loop add markers to this list like

```
for (int i = 0; i < point_new.length; i++) {

                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                            markerOptions.position(point_new[i]);

                        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                               marker.setTitle("Point");
                        marker.setSnippet("this is snippet");
                        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.p));

                        mMarkers.add(marker); // <-- Like this
}
```

**And** to remove markers

```
private void removeMarkers() {
        for (Marker marker: mMarkers) {
            marker.remove();
        }
        mMarkers.clear();

    }
```

hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
private ArrayList<Marker> mMarkers;
...
private void removeMarkers() {
    for (Marker marker: mMarkers) {
          marker.remove();
     }
mMarkers.clear();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The method signature for [`addMarker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)) is:

```
public final Marker addMarker (MarkerOptions options)
```

So when you add a marker to a `GoogleMap` by specifying the options for the marker, you should save the `Marker` object that is returned (instead of the `MarkerOptions` object that you used to create it).  This object allows you to change the marker state later on.  When you are finished with the marker, you can call `Marker.remove()` to remove it from the map.

As an aside, if you only want to hide it temporarily, you can toggle the visibility of the marker by calling `Marker.setVisible(boolean)`.

Similar to [Remove a marker from a GoogleMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692398/remove-a-marker-from-a-googlemap/13692845#13692845)

Answer (score 0):

marker.setVisible(false) worked flawlessly for me for hidding the markers, and I have returned all of them with the marker.setVisible(true). The .clear() was slowing my app a lot. I do not recomend it.