# Map marker won't leave screen once multiple are set on there, only if its single

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem with using Google maps API on Android. I have a button which removes the selected marker off the maps interface, and information about it from the SQLite db that I have set up. Although my only problem is once multiple markers are on the map this feature stops and doesn't remove them:

Below shows the method which removes the marker from the maps and replaces them. As I said this works perfectly fine with a single marker and my testing has been a success, but with multiple it does not work.

I have an onclicklisterner for the markers which displays the information and a popup box for the marker, for the user to remove the marker they must click the marker which sets the global variable to that object then once the remove button is pressed the removeMarker() method is called. The getAllMarkers() method loops through a SQLite db and pulls information and adds to the maps.

**End problem:** Removing a marker when multiple markers are placed on the map doesn't work. Only works when a single marker is placed on the map.

```
Marker lastOpened = null;
```

To remove the information from the db the condition in the if statement returns a boolean value if it has been done:

```
if(this.mDbHelper.deleteLine(lastOpened.getTitle()))
```

**Remove method**

```
 public void removeMarker(){
        if(this.lastOpened != null){
            if(this.mDbHelper.deleteLine(lastOpened.getTitle())){
                lastOpened.remove();
                getAllMarkers();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [`googleMap.clear()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#public-methods) or you can store your Markers in a collection of kind and remove them in a loop:

```
private ArrayList<Marker> mMarkers;
...
private void removeMarkers() {
for (Marker marker: mMarkers) {
marker.remove();
}
mMarkers.clear();
}
```

Here's a related ticket discuss how to remove marker: [Remove a marker from a GoogleMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692398/remove-a-marker-from-a-googlemap)