# Draggable marker for android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I need to use google map in android app to get the address from the users. The customer can drag the marker to anywhere in the map and need to select continue.

But my code is working like already there a marker and if you long pressed then a new marker will come and you can drag and drop anywhere, but I need to remove the first marker.

```
package com.restaurant.grillizadmin;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.restaurant.grillizadmin.Domain.Items;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Geocoder geocoder;
    private int ACCESS_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 10001;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            enableUserLocation();
            zoomToUserLocation();
        } else {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                //We can show user a dialog why this permission is necessary
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, ACCESS_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, ACCESS_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }

        }

        // Add a marker at Taj Mahal and move the camera
//        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(27.1751, 78.0421);
//        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
//                                            .position(latLng)
//                                            .title("Taj Mahal")
//                                            .snippet("Wonder of the world!");
//        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
//        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16);
//        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName("uae", 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                LatLng london = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(london)
                        .title(address.getLocality());
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(london, 16));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void enableUserLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    private void zoomToUserLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> locationTask = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        locationTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapLongClick: " + latLng.toString());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String streetAddress = address.getAddressLine(0);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title(streetAddress)
                        .draggable(true)
                );
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMarkerDragStart: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMarkerDrag: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMarkerDragEnd: ");
        LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String streetAddress = address.getAddressLine(0);
                marker.setTitle(streetAddress);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == ACCESS_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                enableUserLocation();
                zoomToUserLocation();
            } else {
                //We can show a dialog that permission is not granted...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try looking at [Remove a marker from a GoogleMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692398/remove-a-marker-from-a-googlemap).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to make your marker draggable

```
private void zoomToUserLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Task<Location> locationTask = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
    locationTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20));
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)); //HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        }
    });
}
```

For that last line you'll want something like:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)).draggable(true);
```