# Latitude and Longitude used to show the Address on the map

Tags: android

In google maps I can get the latitude and longitude of the point on which ever I touch.
Now how can I get the address of the Latitude and Longitude(reverse geocoding).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9409229/1339473 see this one..

Comment: check out this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9409229/1567588

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Address> addresses = null;
try {
            Locale mLocale = new Locale("en");
            Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(context , mLocale);
            addresses = gCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            Address addr = addresses.get(0);
            ...
            ...
            ..
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

[Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)

Comment: `catch (Exception e)` really?

Comment: why? what's wrong with that?

Comment: if ever exception occurs, you need weeks to find it out :) I guess `catch (Exception e)` is the worst thing in programming you can do.

Comment: The above code usually gives a `Service not available` Exception message, using which we can show appropriate message. And it explicitly asks to catch the `IOException` while calling `getFromLocation`