# How to get a postalcode from Lat and Long?

Tags: java, android

I have been able to get the lat and long, but is there a way to then obtain a rough guess on a local postcode?

I need this to work in the UK.

If this is not possible please say so.

Answer (score 2):

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
```

Postal code (ZIP code for United States), if available, is:

```
final String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
```

(Found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409195/how-to-get-complete-address-from-latitude-and-longitude))

Comment: And of course you need active Internet connection for this to work.