# Trying to convert longitude and latitide to address name but it's skipping too many frames

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to execute the following code :

```
          public void OnLocationChanged(Location location) {


        var lat = (TextView)FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.latitude);
        var lon = (TextView)FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.longitude);
        var stName = (TextView)FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.st_name);

        lat.Text = string.Format ("Latitude: {0:N5}",location.Latitude);
        lon.Text = string.Format ("Longitude: {0:N5}", location.Longitude);


        try{
            Geocoder geocode = new Geocoder (this);
            List<Address> getAddrTask = new List<Address>(geocode.GetFromLocation(location.Latitude,location.Longitude,1));
                Address returnedAddress = getAddrTask.FirstOrDefault();
            if(returnedAddress != null){
                System.Text.StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.MaxAddressLineIndex;i++){
                    strReturnedAddress.Append(returnedAddress.GetAddressLine(i)).AppendLine(",");
                }
                stName.Text = strReturnedAddress.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            Toast.MakeText (this, e.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show ();
        }

    }
```

it all works great and charming, but when executing it, it gives me on the application output : 
[Choreographer] Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geocoder is probably the culprit. Typically it needs to access the Internet to look up the address, and the delay is going to be unpredictable (and could be long enough to cause an Application Not Responding error dialog to pop up).

You should move your try/catch block into an `AsyncTask` so this task doesn't get run on the main thread. I'm not familiar with Xamarin, but you can look up how to use AsyncTask with it.

Comment: Yea i guess i have to use the AsyncTask and am searching all day about it and how to use it.

anyway thanks alot for your reply

Answer (score 1):

OK if you want to use it as Map you can use this

String locationString = @"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=14&size=250x250&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Clabel:S%7C" + latitude + "," +longitude + "&sensor=false";

```
                       webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri(locationString);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but am not using a map in my application. i just want to retrieve the address of my coordinates.

Comment: Have a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409195/how-to-get-complete-address-from-latitude-and-longitude

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely Geocoder that is the culprit. In general, you should perform network tasks in the background so that you don't block the UI thread.

There is a recipe on Xamarin's site on how to use [Geocoder in a thread](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/geocoder/reverse_geocode_a_location/).

Comment: The same problem i am facing, the GetFromLocationAsynce() is not reachable!

Comment: What do you mean "...not reachable..."? Is there an error being thrown?

Comment: ok i solved the problem by updating the mono android from 4.6 to 4.8 and found the GetFromLocationAsync() method.