# How to get address of a location from latitude longitude values using geocoder in android?

Tags: android, google-geocoder

i am tried up with some common set of codes, to get convert the lat long values into address. But i am unable to get that in all the time..
which would be the best option for this. I need this service should be constant. because i need to deliver this to a client.

suggest me a good solution?
Should i have to buy a service from google or yahoo?
Those peoples are providing separate service for this.
My main question is should this "geocoder" will be ok or not??

My code is

```
void getAddress(){
try{
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude,100);

    Log.d("latlong value",latitude +"---"+longitude);
    if (addresses.size() > 0) 
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        result.append(addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
        country=result.toString();
    }
      }
catch(IOException ex){

}
}
```

Comment: Can you upload your code please ? I want to see why you are not able to fetch these details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409195/how-to-get-complete-address-from-latitude-and-longitude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should this "geocoder" will be ok or not?

Yes it is absolutely fine to use Geocode class.

Try out this very simple code,

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
```