# get an adress from coord android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm actually using the maps' API for an android application and I need to get an adresse from 2 coords. So, someone have an idea how can I convert Lat, Lng into an adresse ? 
If it's not possible to get an adresse, is it possible to get a place near this point ?

Thank's in advance!

Comment: Please go through the below link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244763/how-to-get-address-from-latitude-and-longitude-in-android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409195/how-to-get-complete-address-from-latitude-and-longitude Ankit

Comment: Use [Google Reverse Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding), as far as I know it's more accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use geocoder.

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> yourAddresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
yourAddresses= geocoder.getFromLocation(yourLatitude, yourLongitude, 1);

if (yourAddress.size() > 0)
{
 String yourAddress = yourAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
 String yourCity = yourAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
 String yourCountry = yourAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
}
```

Comment: I got an "unhandled exception: Java.io.IOException" for this line : getFromLocation(yourLatitude, yourLongitude, 1); 

I didn't found anything on the net to solve it... Any idea ?

Comment: I just needed to catch the IOException... I definitively need to sleep...
By the way, it works well, thank's for your help. 
Just be careful, yourCity and yourCountry can be null