# how to Location address through network/wifi?

Tags: android, location, wifi

I followed [this](http://javapapers.com/android/android-get-address-with-street-name-city-for-location-with-geocoding/) to get location address including latitude and longitude...

In previous It has only 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

SO I have a small issue in this and its working fine after giving permission
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`

My problem is This process works fine in Network + GPS

So Without GPS its not working... I want to work this without GPS.. It should work only with Mobile Network/Wifi I dont want to turn on <s>GPS</s>

Without Mobile Network/Wifi its working Its showing Just Latitude and Longitude but not address.. with the help of GPS ...... I want to do this without GPS......

But With Mobile Network/Wifi I want to Show only Address..

Can any one suggest me in the Above code...

I followed my articles without GPS but nothing suits for this process.. So I Not mentioned in the question Without GPS.... this is not duplicate.. Please check the code... Because I have integrated this in my app..

please suggest me ..

Comment: In adition to what you have in the manifest add (<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />) --- you can use Google Play Services to get the Location using various methods ie wifi & grps -- here is a guide -- http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/

Comment: thanks @Tasos sir I followed this earlier But its not showing Address... Its showing only latitude and lon....

Comment: Check this to convert lat long to address http://stackoverflow.com/a/9409229/5515371

Comment: Please share here what you do in code. so we can under stand issue.

Comment: what ever In that Link I have done Same.. But its showing Only latitude and Longitude in Offline and sometime its not working...