# How to get Current Location(Street,City, etc,..) using gps in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I want to create a app to Track the Users who installed my App, So i have a following code for tracking, This code working good but it will return only CITY NAME. But i need full details like street name, city, like wise .

```
    public class GetCurrentLocation extends Activity
        implements OnClickListener {

    private LocationManager locationMangaer = null;
    private LocationListener locationListener = null;

    private Button btnGetLocation = null;
    private EditText editLocation = null;
    private ProgressBar pb = null;

    private static final String TAG = "Debug";
    private Boolean flag = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //if you want to lock screen for always Portrait mode
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo
                .SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        editLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLocation);

        btnGetLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);
        btnGetLocation.setOnClickListener(this);

        locationMangaer = (LocationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        flag = displayGpsStatus();
        if (flag) {

            Log.v(TAG, "onClick");

            editLocation.setText("Please!! move your device to" +
                    " see the changes in coordinates." + "\nWait..");

            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            locationMangaer.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);

        } else {
            alertbox("Gps Status!!", "Your GPS is: OFF");
        }

    }

    /*----Method to Check GPS is enable or disable ----- */
    private Boolean displayGpsStatus() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getBaseContext()
                .getContentResolver();
        boolean gpsStatus = Settings.Secure
                .isLocationProviderEnabled(contentResolver,
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (gpsStatus) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*----------Method to create an AlertBox ------------- */
    protected void alertbox(String title, String mymessage) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Your Device's GPS is Disable")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setTitle("** Gps Status **")
                .setPositiveButton("Gps On",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // finish the current activity
                                // AlertBoxAdvance.this.finish();
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(
                                        Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(myIntent);
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // cancel the dialog box
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    /*----------Listener class to get coordinates ------------- */
    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

            editLocation.setText("");
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location changed : Lat: " +
                            loc.getLatitude()+ " Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String longitude = "Longitude: " +loc.getLongitude();
            Log.v(TAG, longitude);
            String latitude = "Latitude: " +loc.getLatitude();
            Log.v(TAG, latitude);

    /*----------to get City-Name from coordinates ------------- */
            String cityName=null;
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),
                    Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address>  addresses;
            try {
                addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc
                        .getLongitude(), 1);
                if (addresses.size() > 0)
                    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                cityName=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String s = longitude+"\n"+latitude +
                    "\n\nMy Currrent City is: "+cityName;
            editLocation.setText(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider,
                                    int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this :

```
public void setCurrentLocation() {
        if (UtilityMethods.isGPSEnabled(mContext)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                requestPermissions(LOCATION_PERMS, LOCATION_REQUEST);
                // return;
            } else {
                getCurrentAddress();
            }

        } else {
            alertbox("Gps Status", "Your Device's GPS is Disable", mContext);
        }
    }
```

Using LocationManager

```
    public void getCurrentAddress() {
        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (locationManager != null) {

            try {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i("msg", "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
            }
            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),
                    Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses;
            try {
                addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                    String locality = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    String subLocality = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
                    String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                    String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                    String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                    String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
                    if (subLocality != null) {

                        currentLocation = locality + "," + subLocality;
                    } else {

                        currentLocation = locality;
                    }
                    current_locality = locality;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, Constants.ToastConstatnts.ERROR_FETCHING_LOCATION, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried `Geocoder', it won't give me the exact current address of my current location. It gives me an array of addresses of all the nearby locations. I want to get the exact current location. I have my longitude and latitude of the current location.

Comment: Very Helpful. I use your technique  to return a string and it works much better

Answer (score 3):

Use [fused Location Provider](http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/) to get current device latitude and longitude.

With the help of latitude and longitude, you can get city name and address.

To get full street name, use [getMaxAddressLineIndex()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19927013/3960700).

In onLocationChanged, check whether you are getting current location or not.

**Edit:**

```
String strAdd = "";

 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

        editLocation.setText("");
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location changed : Lat: " +
                        loc.getLatitude()+ " Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String longitude = "Longitude: " +loc.getLongitude();
        Log.v(TAG, longitude);
        String latitude = "Latitude: " +loc.getLatitude();
        Log.v(TAG, latitude);

   /*----------to get City-Name from coordinates ------------- */
        String cityName=null;


         Geocoder geocoder;
      List<Address> addresses;

    geocoder = new Geocoder(TabClubActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

        try {

          addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); 


     if (!addresses.isEmpty()) {
            Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
            StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

            for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(" ");
            }
            strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();

            textview.setText(strAdd);

              Log.e("MyCurrentLoctionAddress", "" + strReturnedAddress.toString());

              cityName=addresses.get(0).getLocality();



        } else {

    //      Log.e("MyCurrentLoctionAddress", "No Address returned!");

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        String s = longitude+"\n"+latitude +
                "\n\nMy Currrent City is: "+cityName;
        editLocation.setText(s);
    }
```

Comment: @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan inside your onlocationchanged use my try and catch block

Comment: @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan just copy and pate onLocationchanged().I made a change.

Comment: error in `addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);`

Comment: @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan you are not getting latitude and longitude. thats why you are getting an error.follow this http://javapapers.com/android/android-location-fused-provider/ to get laitude and longitude.

Comment: No, getting latitude and longitude as well as City name

Comment: @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan what value you are getting in MyCurrentLoctionAddress.debug and tell me

Comment: @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan put String strAdd = ""; as a global

Comment: @T.KarthikeyanT.Karthikeyan ok

Comment: How to change the frequency of onLocationChange in this case? Searched other messages in the forum, but none of them I could implement.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the `Geocoder` however the results are unreliable. So better go for the nearbysearch googleapi for the result. It provides the city name directly. Here's the version of my implementation.

```
interface Api{
String BASE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com";

@GET("/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json")
   Call<List<ResultDO>> getPlaceDetailByLatLong(@Query("location") String type,@Query("radius") String radius,@Query("key")String key);
}
```

And in the main activity or fragment.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder() 
            .baseUrl(API.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
API service = retrofit.create(API.class);

service.getCityResults(types, input, location, radius, key).enqueue(new Callback<List<ResultDO>>() {
        @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<List<ResultDO>> call, Response<List<ResultDO>> response) {
            tvCity.setText(response.body().get(0).getVicinity());// first object gives me the city name
       }

        @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<List<ResultDO>> call, Throwable t) {
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get address (street name, city, country, etc) by converting Geographic Location (e.g Latitude, longitude) to address. This process called `Reverse Geocoding` [this doc](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address).

You can use `FusedLocationProviderApi()`, but it has been deprecated ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481789/android-locationservices-fusedlocationapi-deprecated/57012410#57012410)). The alternative, You can use `FusedLocationProviderClient()` to get LastKnownLocation, from LastKnownLocation object (contain latitude and longitude), so we can use to get address like street name, city, country, etc using `Geocoder`. [The sample doc](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address) do synchronously. But here i am doing Asynchronously using `AsyncTask`. Hope this Help.

**To get Current Location:**

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
//before public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener,...,...


private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 101;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
private Location mGetedLocation;

private double currentLat, currentLng;

private void getLastLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        return;
    }
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {

                        mGetedLocation = task.getResult();
                        //currentLat = mGetedLocation.getLatitude();
                        //currentLng = mGetedLocation.getLongitude();

                        //start reverse geocoding
                        //little different with the doc
                        (new GetAddressTask(this)).execute(mGetedLocation);

                    }else{
                        Log.e(TAG, "no location detected");
                        Log.w(TAG, "getLastLocation:exception", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

**To Get Address from LastKnownLocation**

```
//sorry, I forgot where I got this asyncTask code. So I did not mention the source. 
//If anyone feels that making this code please comment.


private class GetAddressTask extends AsyncTask<Location, Void, String> {
    Context mContext;

    GetAddressTask(Context context) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Location... params) {
        Geocoder geocoder =
                new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
        // Get the current location from the input parameter list
        Location loc = params[0];
        // Create a list to contain the result address
        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                    loc.getLongitude(), 1);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            Log.e("LocationSampleActivity",
                    "IO Exception in getFromLocation()");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return ("IO Exception trying to get address");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e2) {
            // Error message to post in the log
            String errorString = "Illegal arguments " +
                    Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()) +
                    " , " +
                    Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()) +
                    " passed to address service";
            Log.e("LocationSampleActivity", errorString);
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return errorString;
        }
        // If the reverse geocode returned an address
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
        /*
                    address.getLocality(),
                    address.getCountryName());
        */
            return address.getLocality();
        } else {
            return "No address found";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String address) {
        if (address != null)
        mtextView.setText(address);//=============================> GOT THIS
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Activity Class makes a customized method :

```
  private void getTheUserPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationGetter locationGetter = new LocationGetter(FreshMenuSearchActivity.this, REQUEST_LOCATION, locationManager);


        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

            locationGetter.OnGPS();
        } else {

            locationGetter.getLocation();
        }
    }
```

Make a UserDefined Class name LocationGetter:-

```
public class LocationGetter {

    private int REQUEST_LOCATION;
    private FreshMenuSearchActivity mContext;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Geocoder geocoder;

    public LocationGetter(FreshMenuSearchActivity mContext, int requestLocation, LocationManager locationManager) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.locationManager = locationManager;
        this.REQUEST_LOCATION = requestLocation;
    }


    public void getLocation() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,

                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mContext, new String[]
                    {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
        } else {
            Location LocationGps = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Location LocationNetwork = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            Location LocationPassive = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

            if (LocationGps != null) {
                double lat = LocationGps.getLatitude();
                double longi = LocationGps.getLongitude();
                getTheAddress(lat, longi);
            } else if (LocationNetwork != null) {
                double lat = LocationNetwork.getLatitude();
                double longi = LocationNetwork.getLongitude();
                getTheAddress(lat, longi);
            } else if (LocationPassive != null) {
                double lat = LocationPassive.getLatitude();
                double longi = LocationPassive.getLongitude();
                getTheAddress(lat, longi);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Can't Get Your Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    }

    private void getTheAddress(double latitude, double longitude) {
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
            String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
            Log.d("neel", address);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void OnGPS() {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        builder.setMessage("Enable GPS").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```