# Android LocationServices.FusedLocationApi deprecated

Tags: java, android, deprecated, android-fusedlocation

I couldn't figure out why `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest, this);` "FusedLocationApi" is cross out and point at it saying is deprecated.
[Click here to view Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mML1U.jpg)

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MaintainerMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{

private GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocaton;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maintainer_map2);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
}
```

Comment: How if it is deprecated there is line on this please check I am using this LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest, this);

Comment: @OmarHayat FusedLocationApi is cross out

Comment: check your dependencies I compile using this  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'

Comment: You are using this in oncreate metod  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

Comment: @OmarHayat I was using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.0' and after I change to 9.4.0 it fixed the problem, why did it fix after changing the number?

Comment: [Check location service usage for latest version ](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)

Comment: I have to check it please also check my answer first buildGoogleApiClient otherwise its give you null pointer exception.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi you can check this for recent versions

Answer (score 161, accepted):

### Original Answer

This is happening because `FusedLocationProviderApi` deprecated in a recent version of google play services. You can check it [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi). The official guide now suggests using [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient). You can find the detailed guide  [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#play-services).

for e.g inside `onCreate()` or `onViewCreated()` create a `FusedLocationProviderClient` instance

**Kotlin**

```
val fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext())
```

and for requesting the last known location all you have to do is call

```
fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
            location?.let { it: Location ->
                // Logic to handle location object
            } ?: kotlin.run {
                // Handle Null case or Request periodic location update https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates
            }
        }
```

**Java**

```
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext());
```

and

```
fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(requireActivity(), location -> {
        if (location != null) {
            // Logic to handle location object
        } else {
            // Handle null case or Request periodic location update https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates
        }
    });
```

*Simple, Isn't it?*

---

### Important Update (October 24, 2017):

**Yesterday Google updated its official developer page with [a warning](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) that says**

> Please continue using the FusedLocationProviderApi class and don't migrate to the FusedLocationProviderClient class until Google Play services version 12.0.0 is available, which is expected to ship in early 2018. Using the FusedLocationProviderClient before version 12.0.0 causes the client app to crash when Google Play services is updated on the device. We apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused.

[image: warning]
So I think we should continue using the deprecated `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi` until Google resolves the issue.

---

### Latest Update (November 21, 2017):

**The warning is gone now.**  [Google Play services 11.6 November 6, 2017, release note](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) says : [image: Fixed FusedLocationProviderClient issue that occasionally caused crashes when Google Play services updated.] I think Play Services won't crash when it updates itself in the background. So we can use new `FusedLocationProviderClient` now.

Comment: I love how Google docs still tell you to use the old API: https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: is getLastLocation() doing what LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates() did? What's so strange, up to now, is the documentation pointing still to that old way. It's confusing.  https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#updates

Comment: @JuanMendez I agree. They need to work on maintaining proper up-to-date examples.  btw `getLastLocation()` only return the most recent known location of device.. you can request location update with new `requestLocationUpdates(LocationRequest request, PendingIntent callbackIntent)` method.

Comment: @SomeshKumar, thanks. yes, that's the method I've been using. I am sticking to 11.2.0 in the meantime.

Comment: Look like the warning is gone now (nov 13, 2017), I guess that mean we good to go with FusedLocationProviderClient ?

Comment: My bad! this has been reported hear for 11.6.0: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Comment: @Fraid Yeah,warning is gone.. and the link you provided also states that new version of google play services won't crash if user updates the app. I think I should update my answer now.

Comment: @copsonroad... Really ? Where is warning showing ? I tried searching for a warning on every webpage &  fused client method and found no warning.

Comment: @SomeshKumar I am talking about `FusedLocationApi`, it is showing you warning. The OP asked this API is now deprecated and your edited answer showed the warning is gone. So are you sure you were also talking about `FusedLocationApi`?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Yeah, It was showing warning initially when OP asked the question and after some days Google removed that  warning and put a note telling that everyone should use the deprecated FusedLocationApi. Now everything is properly deprecated. FusedLocationApi is also showing warning. It think you're getting confused.

Comment: @SomeshKumar You said -- The warning is gone now (Latest Update (November 21, 2017). From where has it gone - Docs or Android Studio? Can't say about Docs but in Android Studio it is still showing you the warning.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad There was a warning on official docs.. see Oct, 24 update.

Comment: @SomeshKumar That means you were talking about the Docs warning. Not the warning shown by Android Studio. Even today AS shows you the warning not to use `FusedLocationApi`.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad yeah. You're getting confused with the answer updates.

Comment: And what simple? Your example doesn't have `requestLocationUpdates`, what is difficult with `mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()`? you better give example with `requestLocationUpdates`

Comment: @user924 Question was about depreciation. He never asked about a full API demo here.

Comment: @SomeshKumar Sir will you please elaborate the difference between both why this new Fused location provider client differ with previous one and what problem get solved by new one.

Comment: @NikhilSingh For that you can study the source code of both classes' and find out what are the changes between both implantation.

Answer (score 15):

```
   // Better to use GoogleApiClient to show device location. I am using this way in my aap.

    public class SuccessFragment extends Fragment{
        private TextView txtLatitude, txtLongitude, txtAddress;
        // private AddressResultReceiver mResultReceiver;
        // removed here because cause wrong code when implemented and
        // its not necessary like the author says

        //Define fields for Google API Client
        private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
        private Location lastLocation;
        private LocationRequest locationRequest;
        private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

        private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 14;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);

            txtLatitude = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtLatitude);
            txtLongitude = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtLongitude);
            txtAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);

            // mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(null);
            // cemented as above explained
            try {
                mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
                mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                        .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                                // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                                if (location != null) {
                                    // Logic to handle location object
                                    txtLatitude.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                                    txtLongitude.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                                    if (mResultReceiver != null)
                                        txtAddress.setText(mResultReceiver.getAddress());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
                locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
                if (txtAddress.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                else
                    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

                mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                            // Update UI with location data
                            txtLatitude.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                            txtLongitude.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                        }
                    }

                    ;
                };
            } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            if (!checkPermissions()) {
                startLocationUpdates();
                requestPermissions();
            } else {
                getLastLocation();
                startLocationUpdates();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            stopLocationUpdates();
            super.onPause();
        }

        /**
         * Return the current state of the permissions needed.
         */
        private boolean checkPermissions() {
            int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
            return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }

        private void startLocationPermissionRequest() {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }


        private void requestPermissions() {
            boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                    ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

            // Provide an additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the
            // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
            if (shouldProvideRationale) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");

                showSnackbar(R.string.permission_rationale, android.R.string.ok,
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // Request permission
                                startLocationPermissionRequest();
                            }
                        });

            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
                // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
                // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
                // previously and checked "Never ask again".
                startLocationPermissionRequest();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
         */
        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                               @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
                    // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
                    // receive empty arrays.
                    Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
                } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission granted.
                    getLastLocation();
                } else {
                    // Permission denied.

                    // Notify the user via a SnackBar that they have rejected a core permission for the
                    // app, which makes the Activity useless. In a real app, core permissions would
                    // typically be best requested during a welcome-screen flow.

                    // Additionally, it is important to remember that a permission might have been
                    // rejected without asking the user for permission (device policy or "Never ask
                    // again" prompts). Therefore, a user interface affordance is typically implemented
                    // when permissions are denied. Otherwise, your app could appear unresponsive to
                    // touches or interactions which have required permissions.
                    showSnackbar(R.string.permission_denied_explanation, R.string.settings,
                            new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                                    intent.setAction(
                                            Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                                    intent.setData(uri);
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        }


        /**
         * Provides a simple way of getting a device's location and is well suited for
         * applications that do not require a fine-grained location and that do not need location
         * updates. Gets the best and most recent location currently available, which may be null
         * in rare cases when a location is not available.
         * <p>
         * Note: this method should be called after location permission has been granted.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
        private void getLastLocation() {
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                                lastLocation = task.getResult();

                                txtLatitude.setText(String.valueOf(lastLocation.getLatitude()));
                                txtLongitude.setText(String.valueOf(lastLocation.getLongitude()));

                            } else {
                                Log.w(TAG, "getLastLocation:exception", task.getException());
                                showSnackbar(getString(R.string.no_location_detected));
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

        private void stopLocationUpdates() {
            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
        }

        private void startLocationUpdates() {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);
        }

        // private void showSnackbar(final String text) {
        //    if (canvasLayout != null) {
        //        Snackbar.make(canvasLayout, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //    }
        //}
        // this also cause wrong code and as I see it dont is necessary
        // because the same method which is really used


        private void showSnackbar(final int mainTextStringId, final int actionStringId,
                                  View.OnClickListener listener) {
            Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                    getString(mainTextStringId),
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(getString(actionStringId), listener).show();
        }
    }
```

**And our fragment_location.xml**

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/locationLayout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_margin_30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLatitude"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_margin_0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_margin_30dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/latitude"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLongitude"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_margin_0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_margin_30dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/longitude"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove this line. And rest of the code will work for you

Comment: unable to get location in next interval

Comment: @Vishal i am getting realtime location at every instance you need to check location permission in manifest as well as inside code

Comment: Thanks for your code. But I have an issue, If I need location after every 100 meters and send it to server what should I do? Please help.

Comment: Use like this :                                                                            
  locationRequest =LocationRequest.create()
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                    .setInterval(90000)
                    .setSmallestDisplacement(10)
                    .setFastestInterval(10000);

Comment: foreach not applicable to type 'android.location.Location' 
for(Location location:locationResult.getLastLocation()){

                    }

Answer (score 4):

Use this method

```
mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
```

[In Detail Refer My This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52534719/6667442)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's deprecated!
Here are some points you'll need while using new [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback)).

1. import it as import `com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;`
2. I notice that you are implementing [LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) interface. In the mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates() method, now it doesn't take a LocationListener as a parameter. You can provide [LocationCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationCallback). As this is an abstract class you can't implement it like LocationListener. Make a callback method and pass it instead of 'this' as mentioned in Google's [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#callback). import it as `import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;`
3. With LocationCallback, you'll have [onLocationResult()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationCallback#onLocationResult(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult)) instead of [onLocationChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged(android.location.Location)). It returns [LocationResult](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationResult) object instead of Location object. Use LocationResult.getLastLocation() to get the most recent location available in this result object. Import it as `import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it has been deprecated. `FusedLocationProviderClient` is easier than `FusedLocationProviderApi`, because `FusedLocationProviderApi`usually requires `GoogleApiClient` too, which we need to connect to `Google Play Service` manually. If you previously used `GoogleApiClient`, now `GoogleApiClient`is no longer needed ([more here](https://androidclarified.com/fusedlocationproviderclient-current-location-example/)).

To get last location, can use this function:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
//before public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener,...,...


private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 101;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
private Location mGetedLocation;

private double currentLat, currentLng;

private void getLastLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        return;
    }
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                        mGetedLocation = task.getResult();
                        currentLat = mGetedLocation.getLatitude();
                        currentLng = mGetedLocation.getLongitude();
                        //updateUI();
                    }else{
                        Log.e(TAG, "no location detected");
                        Log.w(TAG, "getLastLocation:exception", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

Answer (score -1):

use getFusedLocationProviderClient instead LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.

**Kotlin**

```
activity?.let { activity ->
      val client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity)
           client.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(activity, OnCompleteListener<Location> {
              // it.result.latitude
              // it.result.longitude
      })
}
```

**java**

```
FusedLocationProviderClient client =
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

// Get the last known location
client.getLastLocation()
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                // ...
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -2):

problem is with your import statement

remove this

```
import android.location.LocationListener;
```

add

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
```