# FusedLocationApi is deprecated

Tags: android

FusedLocationApi was working fine now
"FusedLocationApi" is deprecated why? anyone please check my code

```
public class DriverMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_map);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

}
protected  synchronized  void buildGoogleApiClient()
{
    mGoogleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        LatLng latLng=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
    }



@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}

i think i am near to solve the problem i have checked some other question but never solved for me also i have tried to follow the google [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#play-services) but still i am unable to solve . actually i am following some youtube tutorials and the guy have used it in 2017 i guess and that was working for him ... but unfortunately not for me any one can help me Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that `FusedLocationApi` is deprecated, but currently you can still use it.  Using the new `FusedLocationProviderClient` is cleaner, since you don't need to connect a GoogleApiClient, and you don't need any of the GoogleApiClient callbacks.

Comment: First you want to know why FusedLocationApi is deprecated. How could anybody know that from your code? FusedLocationApi is not your class. Only Google knows why they chose another way. Then at the end of your article you suddenly say that your code doesn't work. Where is the connection to the initial question? Do you even know what deprecation generally means?

Comment: see this post. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481789/android-locationservices-fusedlocationapi-deprecated

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52792253/6401241