# FusedLocationApi is crossed or deprecated

Tags: android-fusedlocation

I really have to find a way to use or find something to replace the crossed line which is FusedLocationApi

I wish you could give me an answer

```
 public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
 locationRequest = new LocationRequest;

 locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
 locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
 locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
 if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
     LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client,locationRequest,this);
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android LocationServices.FusedLocationApi deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481789/android-locationservices-fusedlocationapi-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

use getFusedLocationProviderClient instead LocationServices.FusedLocationApi. check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52456262/4797289)