# 'FusedLocationApi' is deprecated

Tags: android, android-fusedlocation

How to fix deprecation warning exactly for **requestLocationUpdates**.

[Android LocationServices.FusedLocationApi deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481789/android-locationservices-fusedlocationapi-deprecated/52456262#52456262/)
has the answers for it. But I can't understand how to fix it

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DriverMapActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE  );
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);




}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android LocationServices.FusedLocationApi deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481789/android-locationservices-fusedlocationapi-deprecated)

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `FusedLocationProverClient`

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
```

> In your `onCreate` method initialize the `fusedLocationClient`

```
fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(Activity.this);
```

> To request location updates

```
fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
                locationCallback,
                null /* Looper */);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`FusedLocationProviderApi` has been deprecated for long which is why the official guide suggests to usee `FusedLocationProviderClient`. Just call `startLocationUpdates()` to get the updates like this:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (requestingLocationUpdates) startLocationUpdates()
}

private fun startLocationUpdates() {
    fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
            locationCallback,
            null /* Looper */)
}
```

Comment: @shayanmalinda, added the codes how to use it to get the updates & resources. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the FusedLocationProviderClient class. This is the one google wants us to use.

I'm providing you with a short sample.

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private LocationCallbackImpl mLocationCallback = null;
...
if (mFusedLocationClient == null) {

            locationRequest = new LocationRequest()
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                    .setInterval(1000)
                    .setFastestInterval(1000);

            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
            builder.addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

            mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity);
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());

}

/**
  * Callback class
  */
private class LocationCallbackImpl extends LocationCallback {

    private Activity activity;

    public LocationCallbackImpl(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
    }

}
```

Comment: **mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity);**

Comment: activity should be set to a proper Context object. If your code is inside an Activity, just call 'this', or 'YourActivityName.this'.