# how to convert longitude and latitude into text format to show street address?

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I am developing an app,In this I'm using google map to show users current location.

Following code I am using but it doesn't give the result of street address only shows the current location in map and shows longitude and latitude.How do I show the current street address in text field from current longitude and latitude?

```
//java

public class LocationActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView locationText;
    private TextView addressText, textview;
    private GoogleMap map;
    String mob_no;
    private boolean loggedIn = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);

        locationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
        addressText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
     //   textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_euser);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);
        mob_no = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.PHONE_SHARED_PREF, "Not Available");
     //   textview.setText(String.valueOf(mob_no));

        //replace GOOGLE MAP fragment in this Activity
        replaceMapFragment();
    }

    private void replaceMapFragment() {

            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();


        // Enable Zoom
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

        //set Map TYPE
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        //enable Current location Button
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        //set "listener" for changing my location
        map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener());
    }

    private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener() {
        return new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();

                Marker marker;
                marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc));
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));
                locationText.setText("You are at [" + longitude + " ; " + latitude + " ]");

                //get current address by invoke an AsyncTask object
                  new GetAddressTask(LocationActivity.this).execute(String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(longitude));
               // getCompleteAddressString(longitude,latitude);
            }
        };
    }

    public void callBackDataFromAsyncTask(String address) {
        addressText.setText(address);
    }

 /*   @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    private String getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE) {
        String strAdd = "";
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
            if (addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:");

                for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }
                strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                addressText.setText(strAdd);
                Log.w("My Current loction address", "" + strReturnedAddress.toString());
            } else {
                Log.w("My Current loction address", "No Address returned!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.w("My Current loction address", "Canont get Address!");
        }
        return strAdd;
    } */

}



//getaddress

public class GetAddressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private LocationActivity activity;

    public GetAddressTask(LocationActivity activity) {
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(activity, Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(params[0]), Double.parseDouble(params[1]), 1);

            //get current Street name
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);

            //get current province/City
            String province = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();

            //get country
            String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();

            //get postal code
            String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();

            //get place Name
            String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL

            return "Street: " + address + "\n" + "City/Province: " + province + "\nCountry: " + country
                    + "\nPostal CODE: " + postalCode + "\n" + "Place Name: " + knownName;

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "IOE EXCEPTION";

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "IllegalArgument Exception";
        }

    }

    /**
     * When the task finishes, onPostExecute() call back data to Activity UI and displays the address.
     * @param address
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String address) {
        // Call back Data and Display the current address in the UI
       activity.callBackDataFromAsyncTask(address);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get complete address from latitude and longitude?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409195/how-to-get-complete-address-from-latitude-and-longitude)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Double.toString()` to convert a `double` to a `String`. Alternatively, you can use +:

```
"" + latitude
```

If you need more control over the output, such as the number of decimal places to display, you can use `String.format()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void getAddressFromLocation(final double latitude, final double longitude,
                                              final Context context, final Handler handler) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
                String result = null;
                try {
                    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                            latitude, longitude, 1);
                    if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                        Address address = addressList.get(0);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                            sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                        }
                        sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                        sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                        sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                        result = sb.toString();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable connect to Geocoder", e);
                } finally {
                    Message message = Message.obtain();
                    message.setTarget(handler);
                    if (result != null) {
                        message.what = 1;
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        result = "Latitude: " + latitude + " Longitude: " + longitude +
                                "\n\nAddress:\n" + result;
                        bundle.putString("address", result);
                        message.setData(bundle);
                    } else {
                        message.what = 1;
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        result = "Latitude: " + latitude + " Longitude: " + longitude +
                                "\n Unable to get address for this lat-long.";
                        bundle.putString("address", result);
                        message.setData(bundle);
                    }
                    message.sendToTarget();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
```

more info please check below link:-
http://javapapers.com/android/android-get-address-with-street-name-city-for-location-with-geocoding/

its helps to you