# Detect current location and Populate my Activity

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding, currentlocation

My Question is i have an Activity of multiple EditText like Street,landmark,Location,City etc. On the Location EditText i put a button to fetch the Current User Location and Fill the User Address in Respective EditText.
[image]
**NOTE :** i Successfully Fetch my current location and populate my location EditText whole but i want to add street Number in Street EditText, City in City EditText etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html) for beginning and find many examples of "reverse geocoding" like this:

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5

String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); //
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9409229/6950238)