# How to get address location in lollipop and above using latitude and longitude?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am working with `Geocoder` to find exact address of a location using `latitude` and `longitude`, but it didn't support in `lollipop` and above

```
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
String mylocation;
if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
 try {
  List < Address > addresses = geo.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
  if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
   Address address = addresses.get(0);
   String addressText = String.format("%s, %s, %s",
    // If there's a street address, add it
    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
    // Locality is usually a city
    address.getLocality(),
    // The country of the address
    address.getCountryName());
   mylocation = "Lattitude: " + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude() + "\nAddress: " + addressText;
   address1.setText(addressText);
  }
 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Is there any error message or code you can share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use following code for Address:**

```
//Set Address
try {
  List < Address > addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
  if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
   String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + " " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
   if (address != null) {
    textViewAddress.setText(address);
   } else {
    textViewAddress.setText("Not Available");
   }

   String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
   if (city != null) {
    textViewCity.setText(city);
   } else {
    textViewCity.setText("Not Available");
   }

   String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
   if (state != null) {
    textViewState.setText(state);
   } else {
    textViewState.setText("Not Available");
   }

   String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
   if (country != null) {
    textViewCountry.setText(country);
   } else {
    textViewCountry.setText("Not Available");
   }

   System.out.println("Address >> " + address + " " + " \n" + state + " \n" + country);

  }
 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

**Or**

```
String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL
```

refer following link: [Get Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409195/how-to-get-complete-address-from-latitude-and-longitude?rq=1)

Comment: I tried this, both are not working in lollipop and above versions. Is there any other way. please help

Comment: @Jincy: I have run your code in my project & its working fine on My marshmallo device. I am getting my lat, lang and address properly.
Can you please define your actual problem?

Comment: @Jincy: No, api key not required.

Comment: It's working on jellybean, in lollipop it shows latitude and longitude but not address, in marshmallow nothing is showing, no error.

Comment: @Jincy: Make sure you have checked permissions for lolipop. Otherwise make your target version to 21.

Comment: Ok, Let me check it.

Comment: @BK I change my target sdk to 21 now i get latitude and longitude in marshmallow, but i didnt get the address

Comment: @Jincy: In marshmallo, you will definitely get address if you are getting latLng there.

Comment: Thank You so much. Its Working

Comment: @Jincy: Ohh that's great. but which error you had in your code?

Comment: problem is with my emulator, i install it in my real device, then it worked

Comment: @Jincy: For emulator, have you set location from ddms. It will solve your problem.

Comment: @BK: its not working on marshmallow real device, i checked it in lollipop, its working but marshmallow not?

Comment: @Jincy: But I am checking it on `Marshmallo` device. 
My `compileSdkVersion 24` and `targetSdkVersion 22`.  Working fine with these targets in marshmallow.

Comment: Perfect answer BK19