# Getting current location in textview

Tags: android, google-maps

whenever I click on a particular location in Google Map, I want that location's name to be displayed in a text view. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Search on Google

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have already searched it on google.what I found is searching the location from the text view. But not for showing the selected location in text view.If you have any thread can you please provide me here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849497/how-to-get-address-location-in-lollipop-and-above-using-latitude-and-longitude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get lat_lng value for particular location, then lat lng value pass to geocoder method.

```
    public  void getgetLocationAddress(Context context,double lat,double lng){
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;

    geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
          address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
       // System.out.println("SDK_DATA"+address+"..."+city +country);

          //Here address set to your textview
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } }
```

Comment: address ,city and country  are string variables