# How to get geocoded address from latitude, longitude?

Tags: android, geolocation, google-geocoder

I have the below code to convert lat, long to human readable address. Now i am some time getting full details of address including address, city, postalCode  & some time getting only County name like "India". How can i get accurate address based on latitude & longitude?.
Please help me.

```
 final List<Address> list = gCoder.getFromLocation(locationLatitude, locationLongitude, 1);
        if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
            Address address = list.get(0);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            if (address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append(",");
                }
                sb.append(address.getCountryName());
            } else {
                try {
                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(0));
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                }
            }

            strAddress = sb.toString();
            strAddress = strAddress.replace(" ", "");
            strAddress = strAddress.replace(",null", "");
            strAddress = strAddress.replace("null", "");
            strAddress = strAddress.replace("Unnamed", "");
        }
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(strAddress)) {
                    tvLocation.setText(strAddress);
                    Log.e("Location", strAddress + "");
                }else {
                    Snackbar.make(getView(), "Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can check here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9409229/5580210

Answer (score 0):

From a `Geocoder` object, you can call the `getFromLocation(double, double, int)` method.

```
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
    }
    else {
       // do your stuff
    }
```

Comment: location is inaccurate