# Get address from LatLng

Tags: android, location

Right now I currently am displaying the Latitude/Longitude within my Android Studio MapsActivity Marker by using the following:

```
 LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title(String.valueOf(latLng));
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));

    currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker((markerOptions));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
```

My goal is to display the entire address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get complete address from latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409195/how-to-get-complete-address-from-latitude-and-longitude)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use geocoder to get address from latlng

```
Geocoder geocoder; 
List<Address> addresses; 
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault()); 
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5 
String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
```

Comment: Thank you, the reason why I posted this was because I am curious how to change the result of "null" for state, when the user is in a location that is not the United States

Comment: It wants to crash on this line:

  String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine();

Comment: Check that addresses is not null

Comment: Post your logcat