# Get the address from the coordinates Google Map Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api

I'm trying a location app, currently I have the coordinates of that location on the marker. Now, how can I get the name of the location from the coordinates already there?.

My code:

```
//search add address
private void geoLocate() {
    Log.d( TAG, "geoLocate: geolocating" );
    String searchString = mSearchText.getText().toString();

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder( MapActivity.this );

    List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        list = geocoder.getFromLocationName( searchString, 1 );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e( TAG, "geoLocate: IOException" + e.getMessage() );
    }

    if (list.size() > 0) {
        Address address = list.get( 0 );
        Log.d( TAG, "geoLocate: found a location:  " + address.toString() );
        moveCamera( new LatLng( address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude() ), DEFAULT_ZOOM,address.getAddressLine( 0 ) );
    }
}
```

This is my marker

```
// add marker
public void addMarkers() {
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener( new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position( latLng );
            markerOptions.title( latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude );
            mMap.clear();
            mMap.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng( latLng ) );
            mMap.addMarker( markerOptions );
            shareView();
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9409229/4614807

Comment: you are asking a opposite question based on your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get complete address from latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409195/how-to-get-complete-address-from-latitude-and-longitude)

Comment: what do you want to do. can you explain properly?

Comment: Ex: I have a coordinates: 40.657052 : 73.990700 convert ->> = Brooklyn, New York

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bellow code to fetch address base on latlong

```
try {
        Geocoder geocoder;
        String city=null;
        List<Address> yourAddresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        yourAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(yourLatitude, yourLongitude, 1);


    final String yourAddress = yourAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    if (yourAddresses != null && yourAddresses.size() > 0) {
        android.location.Address address = yourAddresses.get(0);
        @SuppressWarnings("MismatchedQueryAndUpdateOfStringBuilder") StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
            sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
        }
        city = address.getLocality();
        Log.d("city", "onCreate: "+city);
    }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```