# Not getting countryname from latitude and longitude

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-location, android-gps

I want to get country name from user location so for this purpose i find latitude and longitude of current location. Now i want to get country name from this lat and longi.
But problem is i am not getting country name, dont know why please check my code and help me.

HomeActivity.java:

```
if (checkPermissions()) {
        if (isLocationEnabled()) {
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(
                    new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                            Location location = task.getResult();
                            if (location == null) {
                                requestNewLocationData();
                            } else {
                                lat = location.getLatitude();   //here i am getting latitude and logitude value
                                lon = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Turn on location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } else {
        requestPermissions();
    }
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address>addresses;
    try{
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 10);
        if(addresses.size()>0){
            for(Address adr: addresses){
                if(adr.getCountryName()!= null && adr.getCountryName().length()>0){
                    countryname = adr.getCountryName();  
                    latlocation.setText(countryname); //but here country name is showing nothing.

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Try putting your Geocoder logic inside FusedLocationClient's `onComplete()`

Comment: tried, but it is giving error "Geocoder" cannot be applied to oncompeletelistener.

Comment: might be your lat long blank please first check with static lat long

Comment: yeah with static value country name is showing but how can i get those variables value from oncomplete() method ?

Comment: [How to get complete address from latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9409229)

Answer (score 0):

```
SingleLocationProvider class


public class SingleShotLocationProvider {
public static interface LocationCallback { public void onNewLocationAvailable(GPSCoordinates location);
}

// calls back to calling thread, note this is for low grain: if you want higher precision, swap the
// contents of the else and if. Also be sure to check gps permission/settings are allowed.
// call usually takes <10ms
public static void requestSingleUpdate(final Context context, final LocationCallback callback) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (isNetworkEnabled) {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        try {


            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    callback.onNewLocationAvailable(new GPSCoordinates(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                }
            }, null);
        }
    }
}


// consider returning Location instead of this dummy wrapper class
public static class GPSCoordinates {
    public float longitude = -1;
    public float latitude = -1;

    public GPSCoordinates(float theLatitude, float theLongitude) {
        longitude = theLongitude;
        latitude = theLatitude;
    }

    public GPSCoordinates(double theLatitude, double theLongitude) {
        longitude = (float) theLongitude;
        latitude = (float) theLatitude;
    }
}
```

}

```
used SingleLocationProvider for getting location and then used geocoder for getting address

SingleShotLocationProvider.requestSingleUpdate(activity,
                new SingleShotLocationProvider.LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNewLocationAvailable(SingleShotLocationProvider.GPSCoordinates location) {
                        Log.d("Location", "my location is " + location.toString());

                        latitude = location.latitude;
                        longitude = location.longitude;

                        Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(activity);
                        List<Address> address;

                        try {
                            address = coder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, 5);
                            if (address != null) {
                                Address address1 = address.get(0);
                              String country= addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                            }


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }



                    }
                });
```