# How to get complete address from latitude and longitude in android?

Tags: android

**How to get complete address from latitude and longitude?**

I want to get following values from Latitude and Longitude in android

Street Address

City / State

Zip

Complete Address

How to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get complete address from latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409195/how-to-get-complete-address-from-latitude-and-longitude)

Answer (score 0):

maybe using google map api can help you to get location detail

Answer (score 0):

```
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
    String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
    String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
    String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
    String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
```

For more info of available details, Look at [Android-Location-Address](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address)